# Dash appears in background when hovering over left images in a row of inline images?

Tags: html, image

**Problem**

I have some inline images on a web page. When hovering over left images (but not the rightmost image) a white dash appears at the border between two or more inline images.

**What I've tried**

I replaced the image with another image but that doesn't solve the problem.

Placing a `br` tag between the images solves the problem but the images are then no longer inline.

Using a span tag to insert a hidden white space between the anchor tags doesn't work.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<a href="https://www.plos.org/open-access/">
<img src="/images/Open.png" alt="Open Access" style="margin: 0px 20px" height="55px" width="70px">
</a>
<a href="https://opensource.org/">
<img src="/images/source.png" alt="Open Source" style="margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px" height="75px" width="75px">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the spaces between your links and `img`s [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/7facqt91/)

```
<a href="https://www.plos.org/open-access/">
 <img src="//placehold.it/75x75?text=4" alt="Open Access" style="margin: 0px 20px" height="55px" width="70px"></a>

<a href="https://opensource.org/"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75?text=5" alt="Open Source" style="margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px" height="75px" width="75px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this all in table or div like this:

```
<table class = "tableStyle" align = "center">
<td>
<a href="https://www.plos.org/open-access/">
<img src="/images/Open.png" alt="Open Access" style="margin: 0px 20px" height="55px" width="70px">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://opensource.org/">
<img src="/images/source.png" alt="Open Source" style="margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px" height="75px" width="75px">
</a>
</td>
</table>
```

Also use this css:

```
.tableStyle {
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: @RajanBalana I tried to edit this solution because I am the owner of the post and the suggestion worked but I had to add some css and style attributes. Please reverse the edit rejection.

Comment: Your solution works with some modification but I think there's an issue with using tables in modern HTML. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a combination of the white space you have between the tags, and `text-decoration:underline` for the links.

So either remove the white space:

```
<a href="https://www.plos.org/open-access/"><img …></a>
```

or set `text-decoration:none` for those links.

Comment: This solution also worked with `style="text-decoration: none"` as an inline attribute of the `<a>` tag. Thank you.